# LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE - results error

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, csv

I am currently creating a system that parses and reformats several CSV files, generating a new 'master' CSV. This file is then imported into a MySQL database using LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE (MySQL version 5.6.24).

Currently - all of the parsing/processing happens within JS/AJAX, which then does a very simple post to a php file which creates the new csv, and then to another php file which handles the import into the database.

```
$thisDate = $_POST['whatDate'];
$table = "stats";
$csv = "dailySalesCSVs/" . $whatDate . "/" . $whatDate . ".csv";
 $query = "load data local infile '$csv'
        into table stats
        character set latin1
        fields terminated by ',' 
        enclosed by '\"' 
        lines terminated by '\r\n' 
        ignore 1 lines
        (Field1, Field2, Field3, Field4, Field5, Field6, Field7, Field8, Field9, Field10, Field11, Field12)";



$result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
```

There are 728 rows in this newly created 'master' CSV - however upon import, 1750 rows are inserted into the table. Running the import query manually in Workbench and MyAdmin works perfectly though.

1750 is not a multiple of 728 - so i knew that it couldnt be the case that the import script was being triggered multiple times (I've confirmed this with a LOT of testing).

I have read that some bugs like this can occur when LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE queries are triggered from AJAX - but this is the only information i have managed to find on this issue.

If anyone has encountered this before - any pointers would be greatly appreciated

UPDATE: -----
All records have been entered twice exactly - although the first field (AUTO_INCREMENT ID field) skips a large number of 'increments' after the correct first 728 values have been inserted.

Comment: Are there empty lines in your file?

Comment: There are no empty rows through the file, however the last row does end with a line-break

Comment: i seem to get some kind of errors every time i try and use a standard function when loading files. So instead I load the file and `echo` out the values to see if everything is loading correctly. then run the insert query.

Comment: I have just tested by echo'ing readfile($csv), which contains the correct amount of rows...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually, it had turned out that this was in fact running twice whilst trying to check the response for errors, masked by the large skip in Auto-Increment ID's.